# Attempted import error: 'useLocation' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-dom

```
React version:
"react": "^16.13.0",
"react-dom": "^16.13.0",
"react-router-dom": "5.0.1",
"react-scripts": "3.4.0",
```

js code as

```
import {useLocation} from "react-router-dom";
const location = useLocation();
```

...... where is the problem ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That hook was [added in 5.1.0](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/releases/tag/v5.1.0).

Comment: And for safe measure, probably should probably install the latest 5.x version, `5.2.0`.

Comment: oh, I have installed the 5.3.0 .

Comment: I have installed version 6.4.2 and am facing the same issue.

Answer (score -1):

Try uninstalling and reinstalling the "react-router-dom" Then, for safety, run `npm i` and `npm start`. Also, if you're using TS, you have to also install "@types/react-router-dom" as a dev dependency